# Using web crypto with old browser like ie9

Tags: javascript, angular, random

In my angular 2 app i have to encrypt some data before sending it to api.
There is library called ng2-web-cryptography for angular 2 but i'm not sure if it support ie9 and ie10.
Is there any library or polyfill which i can use to AES encryption with older browsers?

Answer (score 2):

We built one, see: https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner

You can see how it works in your environment by visiting: https://peculiarventures.github.io/pv-webcrypto-tests/ and choose "javascript".

Ryan